# Regex behaving differently within C++

Tags: c++, regex, mingw

I've written a regular expression that is used to parse out the various elements of a log string in the following format:

> 0|Verbose|General| Logging system initialised
>
> 0|Verbose| Thread| Starting threads...
>
> 0|Verbose| Thread| Waiting for threads to finish...

Expression:

```
regex rg(R"(\s*(\d+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z\s]+))");
```

In online testers (e.g. https://regexr.com/), it works as expected.

When I use it in my C++ program, however, it will split the first log string up as follows:

> 0
>
> |Verbose|General|
>
> Logging
>
> system

I've tried using various std::regex_constant arguments (e.g. extended, basic, ECMAScript) but to no success.

Any ideas why this is happening/what I'm doing wrong? I'm new to Regex

Comment: Could you tell us which compiler ?

Comment: MinGW g++ version 5.1.0. Just tried updating to v. 6.3.0 and the executable crashed on start, but that's a different issue!

Comment: It's certainly a library issue related to the older version.  On gcc online, it works as expected:  https://ideone.com/ifRW8V  Alternatively you could try using the boost version of the regex library.

Comment: Maybe it does not recognize Perl-like shorthand character classes? Try replacing `\s` with `[[:space:]]` (if standalone) or with `[:space:]` (inside a character class) and `\d` with `[[:digit:]]` (`[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]+)\|[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z]+)\|[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z]+)\|[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z[:space:]]+)`).

Comment: @Christophe sorry if this is a stupid question, but how would I go about fixing a library issue like this?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That gives the same response unfortunately

Comment: @MaxFuller 1) try to get the newer MingW version work 2) If the newer version doesn't solve the issue, as a workaround get the boost library and use [`boost::regex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)  instead of `std::regex` 3)  consider moving to another more reliable windows compiler (e.g. MSVC or clang)

Comment: Parsing those strings by hand (with the appropriate member functions of `std::string`) only takes about ten lines of code. I’d skip the regular expressions and do it directly.

Comment: @PeteBecker for sure, it can easily be done in other ways; I just thought it would be a good idea to familiarise myself with regular expressions :)

Comment: @Christophe removed my MinGW installation, cleanly installed the newest version - it now runs using the newest version but the regex has the same response

Answer (score 0):

Day late and a dollar short (:-( ... (:-), but:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string str = "0|Verbose|General| Logging system initialised";
    regex rg(R"(\s*(\d+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z]+)\|\s*([a-zA-Z\s]+))");
    smatch match;

    if (regex_match(str, match, rg)) {
        cout << "is a match" << endl;
        int nSubs = match.size();
        for (int i = 1; i < nSubs; i++) {
            cout << i << ": " << match[i] << endl;
        }
    } else {
        cout << "not a match" << endl;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
[test]: ./re1
is a match
1: 0
2: Verbose
3: General
4: Logging system initialised
[test]:
```

Using:

```
[test]: g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[test]:
```